# PHP Time not sorted in actual time format

Tags: php, mysql

I have three times in my table

```
1467707400
1468211460
1468233180
```

My query is order by asc

**result**

```
02:00 pm
10:01 am
04:03 pm
```

See the results (PHP date('h:i a',1468233180)) are not in asc order

QUERY

```
SELECT start_time FROM my_table ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

Comment: share your query ?

Comment: Its working fine as expected [`check this`](https://3v4l.org/MEVtX). You're only taking `hours` and `minutes` where as you need to check its `date` also

Answer (score 0):

Uchiha is correct. You're only looking at the hours but the days change as well

```
1467707400
1468211460
1468233180
```

is

```
07/05/2016 @ 8:30am (UTC) - equivalent to your 2:00pm (India, UTC +5:30)
07/11/2016 @ 4:31am (UTC) - equivalent to your 10:01am (India, UTC +5:30)
07/11/2016 @ 10:33am (UTC) - equivalent to your 4:03pm (India, UTC +5:30)
```

So the order you get is correct.